# Four-letter words that can be formed from the letters of the word "facetious" without letter duplication

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How do I construct all four-letter words from the letters of "facetious," without duplicating letters?

Comment: Have you studied [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)?

Comment: aces, acts, ates, auto, cafe, case, cast, cats, ciao, cite, cits, coat, coif, cost, cote, cots, cues, cute, cuts, east, eats, ecus, etas, face, fact, fast, fate, fats, feat, fest, feta, fiat, fies, fist, fits, foes, fuse, ices, iota, oafs, oats, oust, outs, safe, sate, scat, seat, sect, sift, site, sofa, soft, suet, suit, taco, taus, teas, tics, ties, toes, tofu

Comment: That word is one of the few I know in English that contains all five vowels once each in order. Another is "abstemious". You can add "-ly" to each to get y, which is sometimes a vowel.

Comment: Don't forget "abstentious".

Answer (score 1):

The total number of possibilities is $9\times 8\times 7\times 6=3024$  If you need real words, this is beyond the scope of this forum.  You need to consult a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's safe to assume your math class isn't setting English word assignments.

There are $\frac{9!}{4!5!} = 126$ unique $4$ letter combinations

For every $4$ letter combination, it can be arranged in $4! = 24$ ways. This is a total number of permutations of $4$ from $9$ of $126\cdot 24 = 3024$.

Another way is simply $\frac{9!}{5!} = 3024$

Answer (score 1):

There are 61 valid English words with your constraints:

```
{"aces", "acts", "ates", "auto", "cafe", "case", "cast", "cats", 
"ciao", "cite", "cits", "coat", "coif", "cost", "cote", "cots", 
"cues", "cute", "cuts", "east", "eats", "ecus", "etas", "face", 
"fact", "fast", "fate", "fats", "feat", "fest", "feta", "fiat", 
"fies", "fist", "fits", "foes", "fuse", "ices", "iota", "oafs", 
"oats", "oust", "outs", "safe", "sate", "scat", "seat", "sect", 
"sift", "site", "sofa", "soft", "suet", "suit", "taco", "taus", 
"teas", "tics", "ties", "toes", "tofu"}
```

In *Mathematica*:

```
Select[
     DictionaryLookup[___], 
       ContainsOnly[Characters[#], Characters["facetious"]] && 
       DuplicateFreeQ[Characters[#]] && 
       StringLength[#] == 4 &]
```

I presume @Misah Lavrov used similar code, above.